# Site looses javascript and layout after installing HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ssl, nginx, server

I have a site that works fine. Today I tried to install a certificate SSL to pass my site to https.

But once I did it, my site opens (in https now) with no layour or javascript working.

I am using a NGINX server with a GANDI SSL certificate. I donwloaded the certificates in the site and added this in /etc/nginx/sites-available

```
listen 443;
  server_name  my.server.fr;


 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/certificates/certificate-99999.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certificates/my.server.fr.key;
```

This is a problem could be related to any configuration of the certificate, or the construction of the pages?

Comment: You did check what the browser says? What did it say?

Comment: Presumably if you look in the browser console, you'll find a lot of errors. It sounds like you have hardcoded absolute `http://` paths in your pages for JavaScript and CSS rather than relative ones.

Comment: I didn't think about it, it is indeed all in http://. I will redirect the http to https and see if it solved the problem. Thank you already!

Comment: There could be errors due to mixed contents... move http resources to https

Comment: It was that. 

I changed the builder of URL to HTTPS, and everything works as before

Comment: @MatheusOliveira Cool.. great!! Anyways would put it as the answer, might help others in future. You can accept it if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your browser console.

There could be errors due to mixed contents... move http resources to https.